# UserControl with BorderThickness FallbackValue and/or TargerNullValue not being used

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I've created a `UserControl` which has a `Button` inside it. I added a **`BorderThickness`** and **`BorderBrush`** property to the `UserControl` and used **`RelativeSource.TemplatedParent`** to map to the internal button.

I want to be able to override the defaults only if they are specified on the `UserControl`. This part currently works as intended.

```xml
<UserControl.Template>
     <ControlTemplate>
          <Button
                BorderThickness="{Binding Path=BorderThickness, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.TemplatedParent}, FallbackValue=1,TargetNullValue=1}"
                BorderBrush="{Binding Path=BorderBrush, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.TemplatedParent}, FallbackValue=Black,TargetNullValue=Black}"><Button>
          <!-- ... -->
     </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Template>
```

I can specify `BorderThickness` on my `UserControl` and have it modify the `BorderThickness` of the internal button, but the default behaviour is lost. Everything that did not have `BorderThickness` and `BorderBrush` explicitly set now has no border at all.

I am somewhat familiar with FallbackValue and TargetNullValue, but as you can see above they are both present.

I can't help but feel this has something to do with the fact that `BorderThickness` is a bit different because you can set it like so and that is the problem with the `FallbackValue` and `TargetNullValue`:

```
BorderThickness="1"
BorderThickness="1 2"
BorderThickness="1 2 3 4"
```

I have also tried setting it this way:

```xml
<Button>
    <Button.BorderThickness>
        <Binding Path="BorderThickness" RelativeSource="{x:Static RelativeSource.TemplatedParent}">
            <Binding.TargetNullValue>
                <Thickness>1</Thickness>
             </Binding.TargetNullValue>
            <Binding.FallbackValue>
                <Thickness>1</Thickness>
            </Binding.FallbackValue>
        </Binding>
    </Button.BorderThickness>
<Button>
```

How can I achieve the behaviour I want? Currently, I can override, but the default values are not maintained.

Comment: The binding will always satisfy though right? So you're not going to be using the fallbacks, and instead you will be binding to properties that contain 0s. It seems like you should instead set those default values in your binding expression as default values on your `UserControl` properties. Or, if you really want the null behavior, make your properties nullable types.

Comment: Could you please clarify "you should instead set those default values in your binding expression as default values on your UserControl properties"? I was under the impression this was how you accomplish that. I did some searching and haven't found an alternative way, but I might just be misunderstanding something.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear. I meant something like `public Thickness BorderThickness {get; set;} = new Thickness(1);` as your user control property declaration.

Comment: Oh ok. I was wondering if that's what you meant. That's a bit of a problem in this case because this property is bound with the RelativeSource.TemplatedParent. It does not have any code-behind at all for this specific property.

Comment: Hmm I'm not following. I thought you said you added BorderThickness and BorderBrush properties to your `UserControl`. I understand that you have no code-behind for the internal button that the values are bound to, but you should have control over the "top level" user control properties right?

Comment: I made a small change to the question. I wrapped the Button with UserControl.Template. I did not make my own BorderThickness dependency property, so I have no property in the .xaml.cs to set a default Thickness to.

Answer (score 1):

The `TargetNullValue` for `BorderBrush` works, since its default value is `null`, you just do not see it since the `BorderThickness` is zero by default. In fact, most of your binding definitions are redundant.

- The [`FallbackValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue?view=net-5.0) is only used if no value can be returned, which is not the case here. Your templated parent binding should always succeed, so you can remove it.
- The [`TargetNullValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue?view=net-5.0) for `BorderThickness` is useless. [`Thickness`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.thickness?view=net-5.0) is a `struct` and never `null`.

If you want to set your custom default values **only for the `Button`** in case of default values on the `UserControl`, you could create a style with a trigger. The `TargetNullValue` for `BorderBrush` is ok.

```
<UserControl.Template>
   <ControlTemplate>
      <ControlTemplate.Resources>
         <Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding Path=BorderBrush, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue=Black}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{Binding Path=BorderThickness, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=BorderThickness, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="0">
                  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
               </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
      </ControlTemplate.Resources>
      <Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}"/>
         <!-- ... -->
   </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Template>
```

Note that I have extracted both properties to a style to make it reusable in your template. If you want to set the default values in the `UserControl` itself, it is even easier, as you do not need a trigger then.

```
<UserControl.Style>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type UserControl}}">
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
      <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
               <Button BorderThickness="{Binding Path=BorderThickness, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.TemplatedParent}}"
                       BorderBrush="{Binding Path=BorderBrush, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.TemplatedParent}}"/>
               <!-- ... -->
            </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
   </Style>
</UserControl.Style>
```

Comment: That was very helpful thanks. I spend much more time working on web applications, my knowledge of WPF / XAML is poor. I have been forcing myself to create UserControls and more reusable code. I really appreciate the links to documentation as well. One follow up question. My original `UserControl` was not wrapped in `ControlTemplate` but the button in your answer is. For mine, was that something that was inferred?

Comment: For anyone who refers to this in the future. Please note that with the second example,  `UserControl.Style` you are unable to use `<Style TargetType="userControls:FontAwesomeButton"><Setter Property="PropertyNameHere" ...></Setter>` to style multiple user controls at once. It seems the internal style takes precedence. The DataTrigger method does not have this issue.